# Polymer Elements from .5 to 1.0

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

My team and I are updating our project from Polymer 0.5 to Polymer 1.0. Is there a list of which core and paper 0.5 elements will be transitioned to 1.0 and which ones will not be? E.G. core-ajax has become iron-ajax but core-list looks like it hasn't been/won't be updated.

Comment: chuckh.github.io/road-to-polymer/ is a great resource for this

Comment: Perfect!! Not sure how I missed this. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the below link can be handy for you.

**Tip:** if you are not sure about the exact name of the polymer 1.0 elements, you can go to the search element input box and type the second part of your searched element from polymer 0.5. For eg. I was looking for core-animated-pages. I typed animated, which gave my result

[Polymer 1.0 elements list](https://elements.polymer-project.org/browse)